# Converting depth map to distance map (Python OpenCV)

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to estimate the distance between objects in a scene and the camera. I have generated a depth map from a rectified stereo pair, but if I understand correctly, that's the distance between the plane where the sensor is located and the objects, but not the camera point specifically.

I am currently solving this by dividing the distance value found for each pixel by the cosine of the angle between the center of the image and that pixel.

[image: depth vs distance from image]

This is for video frames, so I compute the cosines once:

```
depthToDistance = np.ones((width, height))

degreesPerPixel = hFov / width 

for x in range(width):
    for y in range(height):
        distY = abs(y-height/2)
        distX = abs(x-width/2)
        dist = math.sqrt(distX**2+distY**2)
        degrees = dist * degreesPerPixel
        factor = math.cos(math.radians(degrees))
        depthToDistance[x,y] = factor
```

And apply the cosines to the depth map generated for every frame (pair)

```
for x in range(width):
    for y in range(height):
        factor = depthToDistance[x,y]
        depth_map[x,y] /= factor
```

My two questions are?

- Is this mathematically correct? My early tests look good to my eye, but I haven't checked this methodically yet.
- Is there a faster way to do this? I don't normally write Python code, so I may be doing something stupid. In JS, I would use shaders to speed this up dramatically but I'm reusing Python depth estimation examples and lilbraries.

Thanks.

Comment: (1) build synthetic data (trivial ~1-pixel data set, specified literally in the source), consider results of the calculation both in code and manually (2) either express your double loops in numpy functions, or just use numba. numba gets faster, the fewer library functions remain in your JITted code (i.e. try replacing complex/generic numpy functions by plain loops and it will be faster).

Comment: and you need to swap your iteration order and array shapes and indexing. we aren't in fortran here but in C land. row-major means that for best performance (usage of CPU cache), you need to iterate over the innermost (last) dimension the fastest, i.e. `arr = np.zeros((height, width)); for y...: for x...: arr[y,x]`